# Data Entry in Pivot Mode

Tags: ag-grid

Is it possible to change data in pivot mode ? I want to change numbers in each base level in pivot mode. Parents and children should be read-only. I can control it via flag, is the possible ?
Based on https://plnkr.co/edit/REfqahU8KQ1LbUbCgU5Q?p=preview example, i wan't to change lines under year node. So parents will be auto-calculated and read-only.
Probably something like

```
  defaultColDef: {
        editable: true
    },
```

but more controlled.

Comment: I am also looking for something similar .. is there a way ?

Comment: @enthusiast this option will be the only way for me to buy it. I need a data input in similar way.